# Websphere still throws No user specified when creating a connection to secure messaging engine ... on bus

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I created a Websphere bus for JMS(bot Websphere MQ BTW) transmission in Websphere 7 server and disable the security like in the last section of [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0905_parate/) site, but still get

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: CWSIA0006E: The authorization for the supplied user name was not successful.
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:183)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:342)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:225)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:456)
... 20 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.sib.core.exception.SINotAuthorizedException: CWSIP0303E: No user specified when creating a connection to secure messaging engine blahblah.server1-JMSBus on bus JMSBus.
at com.ibm.websphere.sib.exception.SIException.<init>(SIException.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.MessageProcessor.createConnection(MessageProcessor.java:737)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.localAttach(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:451)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.connectFromInsideServer(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:406)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.localBootstrap(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:323)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:172)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(JmsJcaManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:460)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2034)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1711)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2471)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1059)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:696)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:288)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:162)
... 26 more
```

Don't know what else shall I make a change..

Comment: Your bus looks still secured. Did you save configuration and restart the server? If you are running Network Deployment edition make sure that all nodes are synchronized and servers with bus restarted. If you want to use secured bus, make sure there is a user in the `Connector` role  for the bus, and you are using it in connection factory.

Comment: @Gas thanks, restart the server after disable the security on the bus actually resolve the problem. How dumb I am. Please make an answer so I will close this question. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bus looks still secured. Make sure you have saved configuration and restarted the server. If you are running Network Deployment edition make sure that all nodes are synchronized and servers with bus restarted.

If you want to use secured bus, make sure there is a user in the `Connector` role for the bus, you defined authentication alias with that user, and you are using that alias in connection factory.